# How to configure elasticsearch for enabling xpack security?

Tags: elasticsearch

after all the necessary installation for kibana when i tried to do integration to add logs it shows "To use central management for Elastic Agents, enable the following Elasticsearch security features."

when i added xpack security value to true and after restarting the elasticsearch when i'm checking on browser it shows kibna is not ready yet or gives 502 error : service unavailable message: licence is not available

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Filebeat* to monitor the Elasticsearch log files, collect log events, and ship them to the monitoring cluster.
Your recent logs are visible on the Monitoring page in Kibana.

Comment: i have installed filebeat also

Comment: but i'm not able to enable security to elastcisearch so that i can integrate amazon ec2 logs

Comment: Take a look... may help you: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-filebeat.html